# CAMERA: Device below API 24 does not return anything OnActivityResult

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, android-camera, android-fileprovider

Here I start activity to take photo

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = createImageFile();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                if (Build.VERSION_CODES.N <= android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {

                                    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "za.co.keyfleet.driverapp.fileprovider",
                                            photoFile);

                                } else {

                                    photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

                                }

                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
                            }
                        }
```

This is called OnActivityResult

```
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                        String filePath= file.getAbsolutePath();
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);


                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(0);
                            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
                                    matrix, true);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
                            byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                            if (byteArray != null) {
                                mCheck.setChecked(true);
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

The problem is that it works perfectly with API 24 and higher but lower it just returns nothing.I am able to open the camera with both and return without errors with both but only the "newer" phones returns a bitmap and the older just empty. I need to be able to take and return a photo with all android devices.

Comment: "I need to be able to take and return a photo with all android devices" -- then do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. While ideally every camera app used by every user supports `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, that is not required. Also, you will crash with an `OutOfMemoryError` on many devices, as there is not necessarily enough free heap space for you to read in the photo, make a copy of it for some reason, then compress the copy, then encode the copy. Beyond that, make sure that you are holding onto `mCurrentPhotoPath` in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: @CommonsWare what will I use in the place of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. I got the code from https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics. I need the full size photo. The photo then gets converted to bytearray and saved to db.

Comment: "what will I use in the place of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" -- [work with the camera APIs directly](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect). Or, use a library that simplifies those APIs, such as Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android. "The photo then gets converted to bytearray and saved to db" -- if by "db" you mean SQLite in the Android app, that's not a recommended approach. While SQLite supports large values, it does not work especially well on Android. The recommended approach is to keep the images as files and store a filename or some other identifier in the database.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, thank you. I used CameraKit-Android and it works perfectly. Fotoapparat is Kotlin based and hard to figure out. How do I upvote your answer?